# $request->input returns null with Laravel 5.5

Tags: crud, laravel-5.5

I created a form which allows to publish several langs. After defining the langs, I want user to create a default "sector" and save it ...

I have 2 tables :

```
sectors
    id
    admin_id
    created_at
    updated_at
    deleted_at

langs
    id
    langname_fr
    langname
    ....
```

And a pivot table with fields i could fill :

```
category_lang
    lang_id
    category_id
    catname
    catshortname
    ....
```

I created a view :

```
{!! Form::open( array('route' => 'setup.sectorCreate','method' => 'POST') ) !!}
<fieldset>
    <legend>Nom du secteur</legend>

    @foreach($langs as $lang)

        <div class="form-group m-form__group">
            {{ Form::label( 'Nom du secteur en ' . $lang->langname_fr) }}
            {{ Form::text('sectname_lang_' . $lang->id, 'Nom du secteur en ' . $lang->langname_fr, [ 'class' => 'form-control m-input' ]) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-form__group">
            {{ Form::label( 'Nom abrégé du secteur en ' . $lang->langname_fr ) }}
            {{ Form::text('sectshortname_lang_' . $lang->id, 'Nom abrégé du secteur en ' . $lang->langname_fr, [ 'class' => 'form-control m-input' ]) }}
        </div>
    @endforeach
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Description du secteur</legend>

    @foreach($langs as $lang)
        <div class="form-group m-form__group">
            {{ Form::label( $lang->langname_fr ) }}
            {{ Form::text('sectdescription_lang_' . $lang->id, 'Description du secteur en ' . $lang->langname_fr, [ 'class' => 'form-control m-input' ]) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-form__group">
            {{ Form::text('sectshortdescription_lang_' . $lang->id, 'Description courte du secteur en ' . $lang->langname_fr, [ 'class' => 'form-control m-input' ]) }}
        </div>
        <br>
    @endforeach
</fieldset>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I also created a method in order to save the data... I have to create a sector first then attach fields values I must insert into the pivot table (with method attach()) :

```
public function sectorCreate(Request $request) {
    // 1. Create a sector
    $sector = Sector::create(array(
        'admin_id' => Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
     ));

    $sector = Sector::all()->last();
    // 2. getting the ID
    $sector_id = Sector::all()->last()->id;

    // 3. counting published langs
    $countLang = Lang::count();

    // 4. Getting the datas and inserting into pivot table
    for ($i = 1; $i < $countLang; $i++) {
        $sector[$i] = $sector->langs()->attach(
            ['sector_id' => $sector_id],
            ['lang_id' => $i],
            ['sectname' => $request->input('sectname_lang_' .$i)],
            ['sectshortname' => $request->input('sectshortname_lang_' .$i)],
            ['sectdescription' => $request->input('sectdescription_lang_' .$i)],
            ['sectshortdescription' => $request->input('sectshortdescription_lang_' .$i)],
            ['created_at' => Carbon::now()],
            ['updated_at' => Carbon::now()],
            ['deleted_at' => NULL]
        );
    }

    $sector = Sector::with('langs')->get();
    return dd($sector);
    //
    //return redirect()->route('admin.home')->with('success', 'it works');

}
```

Unfortunatelly I have issue with inserting datas ...

```
 #original: array:18 [▼
     "id" => 1
     "langname_fr" => "Français"
     "langname" => "Français"
     "langisocode" => "fr-FR"
     "langshortcode" => "fr"
     "ismainlanguage" => 1
     "created_at" => "2018-04-23 15:09:19"
     "updated_at" => "2018-04-23 15:10:07"
     "deleted_at" => null
     "pivot_sector_id" => 2
     "pivot_lang_id" => 1
     "pivot_sectname" => null
     "pivot_sectshortname" => null
     "pivot_sectdescription" => null
     "pivot_sectshortdescription" => null
     "pivot_created_at" => "2018-04-23 15:47:14"
     "pivot_updated_at" => "2018-04-23 15:47:14"
     "pivot_deleted_at" => null
 ]
```

pivot_sectname, pivot_sectshortname, pivot_sectdescription, pivot_sectshortdescription returns "null"
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

With several research ... I make attachement on $sector_id ... 
and i pass values in an array for the other fields ...

```
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $countLang; $i++) {
        $insertSector[$i] = $sector->langs()->attach(
            $sector_id,
            [
                'lang_id' => $i,
                'sectname' => $request->input('sectname_lang_' .$i),
                'sectshortname' => $request->input('sectshortname_lang_' .$i),
                'sectdescription' => $request->input('sectdescription_lang_' .$i),
                'sectshortdescription' => $request->input('sectshortdescription_lang_' .$i),
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'deleted_at' => NULL
            ]
        );
    }
```